# Globally Apply Decorator to All Controllers Nestjs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, swagger, nestjs

I am creating an API using Nestjs and in trying to scale realized that there are some decorators that I use that are needed for every controller.
E.g `@ApiBearerAuth()`. Is there a way to globally apply decorators on all controllers or all controller methods of a project.

Comment: I wanted to apply the @ApiOAuth2() decorator to all controllers but didn't find a way. Some decorators are supported at application level such as guards, interceptors, pipes and filters but some are not supported. Is there a way to extend the framework to support those that are not currently supported at app level such as @Api[OAuth2, BearerAuth, etc]?

Answer (score 1):

`addSecurityRequirements` might be what you need

```
const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('Title')
    .setDescription('Description...')
    .setVersion('1.0')
    .addBearerAuth(undefined, 'ApiKeyAuth')
    .addSecurityRequirements('ApiKeyAuth')
```

You can then disable it selectively for some endpoints with
`@ApiSecurity([])`